# How to make .bat that runs two commands from command prompt in admin mode with notepad++

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, notepad++

I upgraded to Win10 recently and I keep getting the invalid IP config issue where you have to open `cmd` or `PowerShell` in admin mode and type in the following:

```
netsh i i r

netsh winsock r
```

doing so can take me a minute and I just want to be able to run a `.bat` or something to do it instantly.

How would i go about creating a .bat file that could run these to commands with admin privileges ?

Comment: Your not going to be able to do them both at the same time but why don't you just fix the problem causing you to run the commands in the first place

Comment: It seems so straightforward. Just put the two commands in a .bat file, place it in c:\windows\system32 and make sure the command prompt is started with administrative privileges. Where are you having problems?

Comment: You talk like the problem is widely known, it isn't, you should solve that problem instead of the band-aid fix your using

Comment: I work basic tech support for an internet service provider and this is something that happens every day with customers that have windows 10 and is the only fix i can find for it. If for whatever reason it doesnt work for the customer, we simply refer them to the manufacturer. Seeing as i built the PC and was having no issues with this on Win7, there wouldnt be an exact mfg to refer to.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, the problem, isn't as wide spread as you think it is

Comment: Ok well would you have anything constructive to add to the conversation or would you like to help me with the root of this problem? if you would, i would very much appreciate some insight into what could be causing the issue of my ethernet connection losing the valid ip configuration. more info, if you are willing to help.